# AngularJS Matching ng-model for Select and Radio not Syncing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm having an issue with my models when attempting to sync similar functionality using a select with ng-options and a radio using ng-repeat. The models and details are all the same, but they're not syncing properly and I'm not sure why. I tried to add $parent to radio, based on similar posts on Stack, and that didn't work either.

Basically what I'm trying to do is based on the top-level selection (categories), show the child options (descriptions) based on the parent selected. You can see once you choose a radio option the model will fail.

Here's a plunker to illustrate the issue:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oP0LUEk5u70kLVsM?preview

Here's my controller:

```
$scope.selection = {};

$scope.tagCategories = [
    {
        id: 1,
        tagCategoryName: "Payor Issues"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        tagCategoryName: "Technical Issues"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        tagCategoryName: "Special Project Tags"
    }
];

$scope.tagDescriptions = [
    {
        id: 1,
        tagDescriptionName: "Payor Issue 1",
        tagCategoryId: 1
    }, 
    {
        id: 2,
        tagDescriptionName: "Payor Issue 2",
        tagCategoryId: 1
    }, 
    {
        id: 3,
        tagDescriptionName: "Technical Issue 1",
        tagCategoryId: 2
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        tagDescriptionName: "Technical Issue 2",
        tagCategoryId: 2
    }, 
    {
        id: 5,
        tagDescriptionName: "Special Project 1",
        tagCategoryId: 3
    }
];

$scope.selection.category = $scope.tagCategories[1];
$scope.categories = $scope.tagCategories;

$scope.descriptionsForCategory = function(category) {
    if (category) {
        return $scope.tagDescriptions.filter(function (s) {
            return s.tagCategoryId == category.id;
        });
    }
    return [];
};
```

Associated HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                <!-- NG-MODEL USING SELECT OPTION -->
                <select name='category' class="form-control" ng-model="selection.category" ng-options="category as category.tagCategoryName for category in categories"
                 required>
            <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
        </select>
                    <ul>
                        <!-- NG-MODEL USING NG-REPEAT RADIOS -->
                        <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
                            <div class="radio">

                                <input type="radio" name='category' ng-model="selection.category" id="category{{category.id}}" ng-value="category.tagCategoryName">
                                <label for="category{{category.id}}">{{category.tagCategoryName}}</label>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
                <select name='description' required id="description" class="form-control" ng-disabled="descriptions.length == 0" ng-model="selection.description" ng-options="description as description.tagDescriptionName for description in descriptionsForCategory(selection.category)">
            <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
        </select>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="description in descriptionsForCategory(selection.category)" ng-model="selection.description">
                            {{description.tagDescriptionName}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
```

I'm hoping it's something minor I'm overlooking. Any insight on what's causing the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your `<select/>` is storing the `category` Object while your `<input type="radio">` is storing the `category.tagCategoryName`  String:

```html
<select name='category' class="form-control" ng-model="selection.category" ng-options="category as category.tagCategoryName for category in categories"
             required>
        <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" name='category' ng-model="selection.category" id="category{{category.id}}" ng-value="category.tagCategoryName">
```

In `ng-options`, you have `category as category.tagCategoryName for category in categories`, which says "Store the category object on my scope, and use the tagCategoryName as the display name for each category  in categories"

For your radios, you have the `ng-value` set to be the `category.tagCategoryName` string, so that's what get's bound to your scope. So, the select used the object, the radio used the string. I fixed this by updating the radio to simply use the `category` as the value:

```html
<input type="radio" name='category' ng-model="selection.category" id="category{{category.id}}" ng-value="category">
```

[Here's the working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xQ8UjeqpygFY26UP911H?preview&p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Michael! I knew it was something minor I was overlooking. Muchos gracias!!